# Which paypal / payment plugin should i use with grails 2.0?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, paypal, google-checkout

I'm working on a small ticketshop in grails 2.0 and i want to integrate payment so that the customers can buy one or more tickets.

There are two paypal plugins for grails:
http://grails.org/plugin/paypal
http://grails.org/plugin/paypal-pro

and one shopping-cart plugin with paypal integration:
http://grails.org/plugin/shopping-cart

I don't need a shopping cart, but i need the possibility to add some other payment networks in future too. So that the customer can choose his favorite payment method (ex. paypal, google checkout, sofortüberweisung...).

Are there any available solutions for that or how would you implement such a feature? Which plugin would you choose? Or wouldn't you choose any of the plugins and implement by yourself?

Thanks for answers!:)
whitenexx

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't really make sense as they are plugins for different type of services offered by Paypal.

The Paypal plugin is really not much than a wrapper around the Paypal button (i.e, Paypal Standard), whereas Payment Pro is a separate solution for handling credit card transactions on your site.

The advantage of the Paypal plugin is that you can get started with it very quickly. But you lose a bit of customization as all your transactions happen outside of your server. Payment Pro brings this into your machine, but you're responsible for all the UI for this.

It might be a good idea to get familiar with the differences by going here - https://merchant.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/product_services&nav=2.1

It's more of a business decision.

We use a hosted version of Payment Pro, which skips a lot of the PCI compliance requirements as users don't enter their credit card details on your site. The type of services offered also changes according to who you are and the type of business your company does. I would engage Paypal first to see if you're even eligible for Payment Pro.